# My MacBook slowed down after installing El Capitan

Tags: macos, performance

After I installed El Capitan on my MacBook, it has slowed down considerably. It is not lagging. It simply takes longer to respond as a little red colored wheel is turning where the cursor should be showing. I have not tried anything, because i do not know what to do. Any idea what I can do to speed up again?

Comment: Please make this post look more like a question and include details like system specifics, what you tried, and how exactly the symptoms look (lag, slower framerate, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to make note of the date/time when you see slowdowns. Then you can start using Activity Monitor to see what programs are running, related, not related.

Also, make a brand new user account and log out of your slow account.

Try reproducing the things that slow you down on the new account once you have some idea what causes it.

After a week of paying attention, you'll be able to ask a follow on question with some specifics - is memory over committed, is it disk speed or network speed related? CPU busy? Lots of things to check, and hard to guess what you are seeing without specific data.